# wget runs locally but not from a server

Tags: http, wget, user-agent

I am trying to fetch a url via wget.My wget command is as follows:

```
wget --header "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" --header "Host: www.zomato.com" --header "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" "https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/restaurants/biryani"
```

This runs perfectly when I run it locally.However, when I host this on a server and then run it,it fails.It connects to the host and then waits forever and then fails due to a timeout error.

Just to ensure that it is not because of a particular server,I have now tried this on :

- AWS
- Heroku
- Heroku with Fixie for a fixed outbound static IP address
- Google Compute in different regions
- Netmagix

and it fails every single time. Can anybody give me any pointers as to why this could be happening ?

Comment: Does it really connect? How do you tell?

Comment: https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/restaurants/biryani opens in browser but does zero in terminal. Connects OK but then stalls with HTTP request sent, awaiting response...

Comment: it connects because i get an output file with the html of the page that i have verified to be true

Comment: @PHClaus..can you provide my exact user agent strings in your terminal..

Comment: Very strange, I first thought it might have something to do with the https but this happens also with HTTP version of the URL which redirects in the browser... It also hangs with curl and when using different parameters. It is not connecting from the console with the same browser agent which connects as real browsr...

Comment: Actually, every tool I know for checking HTTP headers and fetching URLs is timing out on every URL from this domain... with and without HTTP(S) Could It be some form of bot protection?